# Correct way of defining the addition operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I was wondering what is the correct way of writing the `operator +` in C++ (assuming I am defining the addition operator for an object defined by a class `c`)?

```
c c::operator+(const c rhs) { /* do addition */ }
```

or

```
c c::operator+(const c& rhs) { /* do addition */ }
```

Comment: Usually, as a non-member, taking two const references (some might argue it is better to take one argument by value, I tend to disagree with that.)

Comment: const c& will be more efficient since you pass by reference, thus no copy will be made

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. But what if I want to write them as member (like in the above)?

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig Thanks. I was also thinking the same way, but I was a bit worried maybe this is not safe enough.

Comment: You should not want that. You may want to implement `operator+=` as a member, then use that in a non-member `operator+`

Comment: @PBM: What does "safe" mean?

Comment: @KerrekSB You are right. I cannot define "safe" concretely here. So, perhaps it is better to ask, is there any advantages with passing the operator arguments by value?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I suppose that's true for leaf code, but for very generic libraries, it might be more efficient to reimplement the non-compound operators from scratch to require fewer copies.

Comment: @PBM: A small amount of convenience perhaps, at the expense of lost copy elision opportunities. If you want to take the argument by reference, you should write two overloads, one for const-lvalue and one for rvalue references.

Comment: You should return `*this` also as a reference, i.e. `c& c::operator+=(const c& rhs) {}`.

Comment: There's an SO post on C++ operator overloading. I would close this as a duplicate, but I don't agree with the suggested way to implement `operator+` in that post.

Answer (score 3):

Let's make a concrete example:

```
class Int
{
    int n_;

public:
    // constructors...

    Int & operator+=(Int const & rhs) { n_ += rhs.n_; return *this; }
    Int & operator+=(Int && rhs)      { n_ += rhs.n_; return *this; }
```

We've spelt out two overloads of the compound-addition which happen to be the same, but we can imagine that the rvalue reference overload provides some increased efficiency in general.

Now how to write  `operator+`? One option is to take the RHS by value:

```
    Int operator+(Int rhs) { return Int(*this) += std::move(rhs); }
```

This version is certainly easy to write and works. It's convenient because we only need a single overload to cover both lvalue and rvalue arguments. But note that this code requires copies to be made: The construction `Int(*this)` is not copy-elidable. So if you absolutely want to not impose any unnecessary cost on the user, you may wish to go the extra mile and reimplement the non-compound operator:

```
    Int operator+(Int const & rhs)
    { Int result(*this); result += rhs; return result; }

    Int operator+(Int && rhs)
    { Int result(*this); result += std::move(rhs); return result; }
```

There is a third option: If your operation is *commutative*, you can return the by-value argument:

```
    Int operator+(Int rhs) &  { return rhs += *this; }
    Int operator+(Int rhs) && { return rhs += std::move(*this); }
```

Comment: Live examples: [Optimized](http://ideone.com/UKI1fx), [Lazy](http://ideone.com/FKAWIU)

Comment: Is there any evidence that rvalue reference overload can provide some increased efficiency?

Comment: @AntonSavin: This is just an example. Consider something like a linked list or a cord class.

Comment: Note that the linked example code, `auto x = Int(10) + Int(20) + Int(30);`, still produces at least *five* constructions. Even more optimized code can do with three: `Int x(10); x += Int(20); x += Int(30);`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the third version inhibits RVO.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Weirdly enough, both the second and the third version produce five constructions in my example. Not sure why I can't get it down to three.

Comment: I looked at this a while back and [it seems I get the same](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/want-speed-dont-always-pass-by-value/).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah... the upshot is this: When writing leaf code, write what you mean, and it will work just fine. When writing a generic library component, it's worth writing code with efficiency in mind, since even a small unnecessary cost may put people off using your code.

Comment: @KerrekSB reduced it to three constructions and one move construction: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18d857e3d726261c

Comment: @AntonSavin: It's not legit to return xvalues. The non-compound operator really must return a prvalue, or you'll break all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of defining operation `+` (and other similar operations like `-` etc.) is to define `+=` operator and then define `+` in terms of `+=`. The operator `+=` should be public member of the class, should accept one parameter by const reference, and should return reference to this:

```
c& operator+=(const c& other)
{
  ... // modify the object in appropriate way, e.g. if it has a member x do
  ... // x += other.x;
  return *this;
}
```

Then it is easy to define `operator+`. It should be a global function defined outside the class:

```
c operator+(const c& lhs, const c& rhs)
{
  c that = lhs;
  that += rhs;
  return that;
}
```

Of course one may define those operators in other ways, and often other ways may be better, but there should be some reason to do so. Otherwise it is best to stick with this default.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should prefer the const reference version because you already guarantee that you will not alter the referenced object and it avoids calling the copy constructor. Other than that, there should be not much difference unless you do some unsafe stuff within the operator+() that would break in either case (like getting the address of the passed object or its members and making unsatisfied assumptions about object lifetime or having flawed copy constructor implementations).

Depending on the semantics of your class `c`, the copy constructor might also have some undesired side effects, but this is something only you as author of the `c` class can know of.

Further, depending on what you are doing in the operator+() and which code of class `c` is directly visible by the compiler, there are chances that the compiler will optimize the passing-by-value case so that your resulting machine code is the same.